# Bessel function of the first kind of order zero in integral representation.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I'm studying alternative methods for elliptic boundary conditions. I picked the formula of Bessel function from this site https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9 I'm looking for any available approach to solve this apparently simple equivalence. Any hint or suggestion for me would be useful. I think I should be able to answer to this question but I still don't get it.

$$
J_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x\sin(\theta))d\theta=
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x\cos(\theta))d\theta
$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I wrote directly the formula on display. I still don't get what kind of context should I provide: I don't get how to solve that equivalence.

Comment: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I edited it. I answered the questions. It should be ok now. Can you please reopen the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With $x$ fixed, the function $\cos(x \sin \theta)$ is a continuous, $\pi$-periodic function in the real variable $\theta$.

Therefore, the value of $ \frac{1}{\pi} \int \cos(x \sin \theta)  \, \mathrm d \theta$ over any finite interval of length $\pi$ is the same.

In particular, $$\frac{1}{\pi} \int _{0}^{\pi}  \cos(x \sin \theta)  \, \mathrm d \theta = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(x \sin \theta)  \, \mathrm d \theta.  $$

Now make the substitution $u = \theta + \pi/2$ to get $$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(x \sin \theta)  \, \mathrm d \theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(-x \cos u) \, \mathrm du  = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(x \cos u) \, \mathrm du.$$

Comment: Thank you. I didn't exploit the periodicity in the integration.